# Ethernet and wireless suddenly not working on Win 7

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, ethernet

My laptop is a Lenovo g530 running win 7. I installed SP1 on 2/8.  My wireless was working fine on 2/10, which was the last time I tried to access the internet before today. Today, I can't connect to any networks.

Diagnosing the wireless says I need to turn it on, but when I press Fn+F5 there's no option to turn it on, just a window with the message "First switch on the wireless device".

I can't connect by plugging in an ethernet cable either; that just shows "unidentified network" and prompts me to power cycle the modem. I know the modem is fine because another laptop in the room is able to access the internet with wireless.

Everything looks normal in device manager.

How can I further diagnose the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Old question, but it turned out that I hadn't switched on the physical switch on the front of the laptop that turns the wireless network on and off.  Once I found that and switched it on, I was able to access the internet.

Answer (score 0):

If it is not hardware try to repair winsock. Click on Start button. Type Cmd in the Start Search text box. Press Ctrl-Shift-Enter keyboard shortcut to run Command Prompt as Administrator. Allow elevation request. Type "netsh winsock reset" without the quotes in the Command Prompt shell, and then press the Enter key. Restart the computer.

Comment: Also try rebooting your router.